# Issue with To field in Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to create an email and save it to a user's drafts folder which is currently working fine. However the email has a giant To field and doesn't properly send when the users sends the email from their drafts folder. Any ideas? This issue only seems to appear in Outlook 2016. This is my save method currently.[image]

```
public void Save(string saveToEmailAddress, string recipient, string subject, IEnumerable<MailAttachment> attachments)
        {
            try
            {
                // We need to impersonate the User whose account we are adding a Draft email to
                _exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, saveToEmailAddress);

                var email = new EmailMessage(_exchangeService)
                {
                    Subject = subject
                };
                email.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);

                foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                {
                    email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attachment.FileName, attachment.Content);
                }
                email.Save();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop impersonating the User account
                // If this doesn't happen, any email sent from this Service
                // will appear to be coming from the Impersonated account (not the Intranet)
                _exchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Almost seems like your `recipient` parameter might have some whitespace you need to strip out? Should probably specify that you're saving this to the Drafts folder in the code so it's more explicit as to what it's doing. `email.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);`

Comment: Yep you were right. There were some cases where I was adding a blank recipient which was causing the issue.

Comment: Sweet, glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to the below code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app;
                try
                {
                    app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
                }
                catch
                {
                    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                }

                if (app == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                string stringHtmlBodyfromFile = File.ReadAllText(@"codeFileUrl");
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as
                                                                     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
                mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
                mailItem.Subject = “subject”;
               mailItem.Recipients.Add("");
                mailItem.HTMLBody = stringHtmlBodyfromFile;
                mailItem.CC = cc;

                mailItem.Attachments.Add(@"AttachmentUrl");
                mailItem.Save();
                        }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
               // XtraMessageBox.Show(eX.Message + "\n" + eX.StackTrace + "\n" + eX.Source + "\n" + eX.InnerException);
            }
```